# Any simple(ish) way to warp a .png?

Tags: mesh, image, 2d

new to Blender but really enjoying it. There is one specific effect that i've used a fair bit in After-effects & fusion which is grid/mesh warp. Basically the software adds in a predefined number of mesh/warp points, & you can drag them out to create interesting effects.

This is a simple animation I made using grid-warp to give the impression the tree was swaying gently in the wind.

https://www.harrisonillustration.com/animation/hjhxcsgb01tiqjhj9i2d1ob0fgmpvx

Attached is an After-effects screen grab.

[image]

I've imported an alpha channel .PNG into blender as a plane, but have been stuck for days as to an easy way to warp it.

Any help much appreciated.

[image]

---

Ok that sounds hopeful :) ..any links to tutorials?....since posting the question I've got as far as using ‘loop cut’ in edit mode to make a grid, & this can be deformed, but there doesn’t seem  to be a way to keyframe the deformation..

[image]

Comment: The best is probably to begin with a mesh that roughly follows the tree shape. Then you could use physics, but the simplest way to do it is probably to parent the drawing to an armature and then make the bones move the way you want. Another method would be shapekeys. Also hook vertices to empties...

Comment: ..sorry, have added an answer/question below..couldn't work out how to add an image to a comment

Comment: oh dear, the mod deleted my 'answer' then deleted the original after-affects screen grab so the questions makes less sense. I love over eager forum police 

Comment: edit your question

Comment: Yes. I’ve edited it now . Got as far as warping,but can’t keyframe the changes

Answer (score 2):

I guess one of the easiest way will be to use shapekeys, but it requires a bit of knowledge (I would personally prefer bones but it needs to know a bit of rigging). If I make it short:

- Create your tree image. Save it as a PNG with transparent background. Import your image as a background, create a mesh and roughly follow the tree shape.

[image]

- Unwrap your mesh, open the *UV/Image* editor and put the UV map over the tree image. Give your mesh a material with the image tree as *Image Texture*. Use the *Image Texture Alpha* socket as a *Factor* in a *Mix Shader* that will mix the *Image Texture* node and a *Transparent* node, so that the object is transparent.

[image]

- Select your object in *Object* mode, go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Shape Keys*, create 2 shapekeys. Go in *Edit* mode, select the second shapekey, move your object vertices to deform your tree the way you want.

[image]

- Back in *Object* mode, keep the second shapekey selected, play with its value to make the tree move. To animate through time, create keyframes: put the cursor over the value and press <kbd>i</kbd>. Open the *Dopesheet* to move the keyframes if necessary.

[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for this reply..i got as far as discovering 'Shape keys' yesterday, so was on the right track ;) Will go through your example now. thanks again

Comment: ..sorry, really stuck at the second step. Ive imported the alpha .png as a background image..then its this bit " create a mesh and roughly follow the tree shape "...i can't  find any way to draw around the object in the way you've shown. sorry to be so inexperienced

Comment: put the image as a background (or in 2.8 just import the image), create a plane, then go in Edit mode and move the vertices of the plane, extrude to extend it, etc...